# AngularJS - RestAngular - after post add new category, update category list in other controller

Tags: angularjs, restangular

what is the best way to update a list of categories (in a nav for example) after adding a category with a different controller?
Here is my code

```
// add new category
app.controller('AddCategoryController', ['$scope', 'CategoryService', function($scope, CategoryService) {

  $scope.category = {};

  $scope.added = false;

  $scope.addCategory = function() {
    CategoryService.addCategory($scope.category).then(function(response) {
        if(response == 'ok') {
            $scope.added = true;
        }
    });
  };
}]);
```

and here is the controller for showing the categories

```
app.controller('CategoriesController', ['$scope', 'CategoryService', function($scope, CategoryService) {
  CategoryService.getCategories().then(function(categories) {
    $scope.categories = categories;
  });
}]);
```

Categories are shown in a nav

```
<nav>
  <div class="list-group" ng-controller="CategoriesController">
    <a ng-href="#category/{{category.id}}" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-bind="category.name"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#add-category" class="list-group-item">Add category</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**EDIT** This is the service

```
services.factory('CategoryService', ['$route', 'Restangular', function($route, Restangular) {
  var Category = Restangular.all('categories');

  return {
    getCategories: function() {
        return Category.getList();
    },
    getCategory: function(id) {
        id = id ? id : $route.current.params.categoryId;
        return Category.get(id);
    },
    addCategory: function(category) {
        return Category.post(category);
    },
    editCategory: function(category) {
        return category.put()
    },
    removeCategory: function(id) {
        id = id ? id : $route.current.params.categoryId;
        return Category.remove(id);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: add more info if you have a specific issue. In general your approach (using a service) is fine.

Comment: once your scope updates, your category list should be updated as well automatically. maybe fetch categories after you add a new one, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are singleton in AngularJS. Therefore, after you called `CategoryService.addCategory` you can update the category list in your service and it will be available for other controllers.

You can also enrich your service to cache the categories. This will help you to avoid unnecessary requests to your backend.

Either you build your own caching logic or use:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
```

In addition you can use `$rootScope.$on` and `$rootScope.$emit` to receive and send events. This helps you to communicate between components in *real-time* fashion.

```
 // send event
$rootScope.$emit(nameOfEvent, args...);
```

In some other controller/ service

```
// subscription
var unbind = $rootScope.$on(nameOfEvent, function(event, args...) { /* do stuff */ });

// don't forget to unbind
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { 
  unbind(); 
});
```

Comment: Actually I fetch categories only from the server, I edited the post with the service I'm using

Comment: use caching (there is a standard feature) - see update for some ideas

Comment: The nav is part of the layout, categories will be fetched only once, I don't need caching in this case, but thanks :)
Solutions with $rootScope.$on works fine
I had to remove the var unbind = .... and the call to unbind after that, that way doesn't worked for me, so I left only $rootScope.$on
Thank you very much!! +1

Comment: Great! But it is important to unbind to avoid memory leaks. I updated the sample. Link to call to `unbind()` to the destruction of the controller.